# Date/Time Conversion ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, datetime-format, iso8601

I'm working with a script that displays the date and time in ISO 8601 format like so: `2012-05-17T17:35:44.000Z`.

but I would like it to display in the normal ColdFusion timestamp format when using the `#Now()#` notation
... so in this format: `{ts '2012-05-17 17:35:44'}`

How can I do this?

Comment: Ha! I thought the title said "confusion"

Comment: No wonder. All that reading upside down made you confused ;)

Answer (score 5):

As of CF 10, ISO-8601 is supported directly by [parseDateTime](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html).

```
<cfset string = "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00">
<cfset date = parseDateTime(string, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")>
```

[Runnable Example on TryCF.com](http://trycf.com/gist/6dadca18c464c804c679cccc5003a0f1/acf?theme=monokai)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure just a parse and then output will give it to you in the format you want :

```
#parseDateTime(REReplace("2012-05-17T17:35:44.000Z", "(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})T([\d:]+).*", "\1-\2-\3 \4"))#
```

Edit: Fixed and tested.  ;)

Comment: No, I think you need something like http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=1129 . Though you may want to adapt the udf as it ignores a) seconds and b) time zone,

Comment: Lol, much better. ISO dates make my head hurt ;) Fyi, if you need the time zone see the `ConvertIsoToDateTime` function [in the comments here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/811-Converting-ISO-Date-Time-To-ColdFusion-Date-Time.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a more complete solution and elegant solution :

```
        <cffunction name="ConvertISOToDateTime" access="private" returntype="date">
    <cfargument name="ISODateString" required="yes" type="string" hint="Properly formed ISO-8601 dateTime String">
    <cfscript>
        // time formats have 2 ways of showing themselves: 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z UTC format OR 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00
        local.initial_date = parseDateTime(REReplace(ISODateString, "(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})T([\d:]+).*", "\1-\2-\3 \4"));
        // If not in UTC format then we need to
        if (right(arguments.ISODateString, 1) neq "Z") {
            local.timeModifier = "";
            //Now we determine if we are adding or deleting the the time modifier.
            if (ISODateString contains '+' and listlen(listrest(ISODateString,"+"),":") eq 2){
                local.timeModifier = listrest(ISODateString,"+");
                local.multiplier = 1; // Add
            } else if (listlen(listlast(ISODateString,"-"),":") eq 2) {
                local.timeModifier = listlast(ISODateString,"-");
                local.multiplier = -1; // Delete
            }
            if (len(local.timeModifier)){
                local.initial_date = dateAdd("h", val(listfirst(local.timeModifier,":"))*local.multiplier,local.initial_date);
                local.initial_date =  dateAdd("m", val(listlast(local.timeModifier,":"))*local.multiplier,local.initial_date);
            }
        }
        return local.initial_date;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with CF2016, Tim Sylvester's answer becomes :

```
<cfset string = "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00">
<cfset date = parseDateTime(string, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:nn:ssX")>
```

The `mm` mask has been deprecated and replaced with `nn`, which was not available with CF10 and CF11.

**Warning** : the `mm` mask behaviour also changed with CF2016 (+ 2018 & 2021), and the previous example would output `{ts '1998-08-16 18:00:30'}`.

Comment: Good to know.  While specifying the mask explicitly is better IMO, apparently it's supported out of the box now i.e. `parseDateTime(string)`, no mask required.

Comment: True. I did some tests: 'now' started with CF11

Answer (score 0):

That date string is in ISO format, there is a good example of how to convert it to a CF date object [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/811-Converting-ISO-Date-Time-To-ColdFusion-Date-Time.htm):

```
...
<cfreturn ARGUMENTS.Date.ReplaceFirst(
    "^.*?(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})T([\d:]+).*$",
    "$1-$2-$3 $4"
    ) />
```

Comment: Answers that are just links are not answers. Please at least provide a summary of what will be found there. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use `createOdbcDate` function. It is best to compare in query.

```
<cfquery name="GetVisits" >
    SELECT v.ExecutiveID, eu.firstname, eu.lastname from Visits where
v.visitDate between #CreateODBCDate(DateFrom)#
        AND  #CreateODBCDate(DateTo)#
</cfquery>
```

Comment: `CreateODBCDate` cannot parse the string `2012-05-17T17:35:44.000Z`. Not to mention it returns a date only, not a date *and* time {ts '2012-05-17 17:35:44'}