# Coldfusion invalid date format

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

How do I convert the following date string (from a Youtube video) to a simple mm/dd/yyyy date string?

2014-11-09T18:36:16.000Z

I have tried the following:

```
DateConvert("utc2local","2014-11-09T18:36:16.000Z")
DateFormat("2014-11-09T18:36:16.000Z",'m/d/yyyy')
```

Both of these throw a error:
*2014-11-09T18:36:16.000Z is an invalid date or time string.*

Is this even a valid date, or is Youtube returning a slightly incorrect format? It does look correct according to this spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: It is in ISO 8601 format. Last I checked there were no built in functions which handle this format, however [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643947/date-time-conversion-coldfusion/12837367) has a number of suggestions, check also cflib.org.  Since this question has already been asked and answered, voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: *voting to close as a duplicate* Henry beat me to it ;-)  coderMe - Tip for next time, if you encounter an unknown date string format, do a quick search on the mask first. Searching on something like yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss Z would have turned up the links above.

Comment: My apologies, everyone! Thanks for the tip, @Leigh. Obviously, I couldn't search for "ISO 8601 coldfusion" if I didn't know it was in ISO 8601 format. :)

Comment: Exactly. We have all been there. But if you cannot find it one way .. try a different angle ;-)

Comment: See, I figured if Ben Nadel hadn't blogged about it, it didn't exist... :)